# Displaying number 0 to 9 in a common Cathode 7 segment display

Tags: gpio

I am using Raspberry pi to display 0 to 9 in a common cathode 7-segment display. A Raspberry pi only has 4 power sources but a common cathode 7 segment needs me to control all the 7 segments individually. Can I still display 0 to 9 in the common cathode 7-segment with just Raspberry pi, resistor and 7 segment? Or do I need a BCD to 7 segment decoder in between? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: "A Raspberry pi only has 4 power sources" ??? What research have you done?

Comment: two 5 V and two 3.3 V.

Comment: GPIO 1 and 17 for 3.3V and GPIO 2 and 4 for 5 V. If I am missing something please let me know I am very new to it.

Comment: think about this ... your house has only three wires connected to the power company grid ... how is it possible that you have more than two power outlets in your house?

Comment: Yes, I totally get that from those 4 power supplies I can create many more, but the problem is I have to individually control those 7 segment. If I connected same power supply on two of them, they are always on or off at the same time. I am still missing something.

Comment: Simple answer **DON'T use ANY of the power pins** you will blow the Pi up is you use 5V and you can't control 3.3V. You need to search some of the many tutorials.

Comment: Are you talking about [this connector](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-raspberry-pi-gpio-and-physical-computing/gpio-pins-overview)? Pins 1, 2, 4, and 17 on that connector are not GPIO pins. Those are  _power_ pins. They're "on" all the time. Software can't control them. The GPIO pins (the pins that software potentially _can_ control) are the ones that have "GPIO" in their names. (e.g., pin 13 on the connector, which is named "GPIO 27".)

Answer (score 0):

There is python support for a 7 segment display in https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/recipes.html?highlight=7-segment%20display#ledchardisplay

This includes details of how to interface to a Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Limit in number of wires is usually solved by using cheap standard shift registers from 74HC595 series (for example [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc595.pdf)). Each one will give you 8 output pins, and you can cascade them (without using up more pins from Pi), to get for example 4*8=32 pins. It's very easy and straight forward to use.